# node.js express routing db dependent

Tags: javascript, node.js

What i'm trying to do:
If the url exists in the db use static page template, if not, display specific page template. Can't seem to figure out, how too...

**My app.js file**

```
  app.get('*', function(req, res){
  var currenturl = req.url;
  console.log('URL IS: ' + my_path)
  if (!!db.get(my_path) ) 
    {
      //If it does exist in db
      console.log('Does exist');
      res.render('index', { thetitle: 'Express', title: db.get(currenturl).title, content: db.get(currenturl).content });
    }else{
      //If it doesn't exist in db
      redirect to other sites
      Like: 
      if you go to "/page" it will run this => app.get('/page', routes.index)
      or "/users" will run => app.get('/users', routes.users)
    }
 });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to create your own simple middleware. Just make sure you put it above the `express.router`

```
app.use(function(req, res, next){
  if (!!db.get(my_path)) {
    // render your site from db
  } else {
    // call next() to continue with your normal routes
    next();
  }
});

app.get('/existsInDB', function(req, res) {
  // should be intercepted by the middleware
})

app.get('/page', function(req, res) {
  // should not be intercepted
  res.render('page')
})
```

Answer (score 0):

using [express](http://expressjs.com/api.html#res.render) is easy. you can use the `redirect` function:

```
if (url_exists) res.render('index');
else res.redirect('/foo/bar');
```

Comment: I'm not sure it's that what i'm searching for. I have updated my OP post, in hope to make myself more clear.